# Given $f(x)$ and asymptotic series $\phi_n(x)$ how to determine if expansion exists?

Tags: asymptotics

Given a function $f(x)$ and an asymptotic series $\phi_n(x)$ as $x\rightarrow x_0$. What is the easiest way to determine if the asymptotic expansion of $f(x)$ exists when using the series $\phi_n(x)$?

Comment: This is a good question. I'm not sure what techniques exist for this, but I often use numerical tools to try to calculate the coefficients in such an expansion. This often leads me to conclusions like "the expansion seems to have only odd powers of $x$" or "there are probably some powers of logarithms mixed in since these limits don't seem to exist". I then follow up these methods with analytical approaches which could yield the types of expansions I expect.